# html video not working in apple devices

Tags: ios, html, video

I have html video tag on my page it works fine in all desktop browsers, and in android devices but its not even showing in apple devices.

```
<div class="item video "> 
  <video loop preload="auto">
    <source src="./video/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="./video/webm/video1.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: You need an HLS streaming to play video on the iOS device. Have you done that? You cannot play video directly pointing to video file

Answer (score 0):

Web video does not play automatically on mobile devices because of bandwidth considerations.

https://www.aerserv.com/why-does-video-autoplay-on-mobile-devices-not-work/

Comment: yeah, but mine is not even showing in the mobile device. and can we make it auto play with some script triggered on events??

Comment: What should it show? There’s no play button because it set to auto play. I don’t know of any way to make it for you play and no one would want that because everybody understands that video should not play

Comment: even if its not autoplaying. it would show the video right?? or only if i remove the auto play  video will show??

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be any other circumstance than to not autoplay.  YouTube does indeed work on a phone.

Comment: actually i found a way that autoplay works...even in iphone 7 & + , recent android device with chrome beta